# How do I calculate frictional forces of an object sliding laterally on a sloped plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction, velocity, free-body-diagram

Game developer here. Most problems about objects sliding down sloped planes with friction are about the object sliding in the natural downward sliding direction of the slope. But how would you calculate the frictional forces on an object sliding in some arbitrary direction on a sloped plane?

My initial thought is to calculate a lateral slope axis and a downward slope axis using cross products with the slope normal and the up vector (working in 3d of course). Then project the object's current velocity onto those 2 axes and apply normal friction without multiplying by Cos(slopeAngle) to the part of the velocity projected onto the lateral axis (since that axis is flat) and apply the standard slope friction to the part of the velocity projected onto the downward slope axis. But that feels like too much friction when I imagine that scenario. Is that the right approach?

Edit: My second thought is to instead just stick close to the slope friction formula and have the frictional force be -velocityDirection * gravity * mass * frictionCoefficient * Cos(slopeAngle) and not split up the velocity into parts. This feels more right to me.

Still I’d love if someone could tell me the correct approach.

Comment: The object will be sliding both down the plane and across the plane

Answer (score 0):

Under the simple kinetic friction model, $\mu_k N$ is the strength of the friction force, full stop, independent of the direction of motion. Then, the *direction* of the kinetic friction opposes the direction of sliding.

Therefore, if you're working in a coordinate system where $y$ points down the slope and $x$ points perpendicular to the slope, you'll need to break the friction force ($\mu_k N$) into components along these two directions in order to get the components of the force, i.e., you'll need an $f_{k,x} = \mu k N \cos\varphi$ and an $f_{k,y} = \mu k N \sin\varphi$.  This angle is the angle between the direction of motion (direction of $\vec{v}$) and the $x$-axis (direction perpendicular to the largest slope).  This angle does *not* depend on the (vertical) angle of the slope itself.

---

If the vertical angle of the ramp (defining its slope) is $\theta$, then the magnitude of the normal force is $N = m g\cos\theta$. Thus, the magnitude of the friction force is $\mu_k mg\cos\theta$.  According to the picture below, we have a coordinate system in which $y$ points straight down the ramp (in the steepest direction), $x$ points along the ramp (in a direction where the height isn't changing), and $z$ points perpendicular to the ramp (out of the screen).  Then,  if you're working in this coordinate system, the friction force (direction anti-parallel to $\vec{v}$) must be broken up into components along $x$ and $y$, as shown. Then, we have
\begin{align}
f_{k,x} &= \mu_k mg\cos\theta \cos\varphi_v\,,\\
f_{k,y} &= \mu_k mg\cos\theta \sin\varphi_v\,,
\end{align}
and since the direction of $\vec{v}$ will be changing (there is a force down the ramp but not across it), the components of the friction force will change due to $\varphi_v$ changing, and hence they'll need to be updated over time.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! You wrote N = mgsincos(angle). What is sincos? Did you perhaps just mean cos(angle)?

Comment: @Josh Sorry that was a typo. IT's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

For some arbitrary motion we can separate the instantaneous velocity of its motion into components across and down the surface of the wedge, the *x* and *y* directions in the figure. Likewise the kinetic friction force acting in the direction of motion can be separated into *x* and *y* components.

The magnitude of the friction force opposing the motion is given by

$$F_{f}=\mu_{k}N=\mu_{k} mg\cos\theta$$

Its components are then

$$F(t)_{f x}=\mu_{k} mg\cos\theta\cos\beta(t)$$
$$F(t)_{f y}=\mu_{k} mg\cos\theta\sin\beta(t)$$

Where the time varying angle $\beta(t)$ is between the friction force and the x-axis

Although the velocity and its components will be changing in time, the magnitude of the friction force $F_{f}$, if considered independent of velocity (as is generally the case), will be constant. However its components, $F(t)_{fx}$ and $F(t)_{fy}$, will be changing in time since the angle $\beta(t)$ will be increasing in time.

Given a wide enough wedge and enough time, eventually $\beta=90^0$, $F_{fx}=0$, and $F_{y}=\mu_{k}mg\cos\theta$.

Hope this helps.

[image]